# How to access passed in fragment shader data in Metal?

Tags: graphics, metal

Just as you use the qualifier `[[ buffer(n) ]]` to access information passed to a vertex shader in Metal, how can I data passed in using the `setFragmentBuffer` or `setFragmentBytes`? `buffer` isn't a valid qualifier for the fragment shader, and apparently `texture` and `color` both have other usage scenarios. I just want to pass in my own custom data like a uniform color or current system time for an entire primitive drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `buffer` **is** a valid qualifier for fragment shader. What makes you think it isn't?

You do it just the same way for a fragment shader as you do for a vertex shader.

Comment: I get an error from XCode telling me that 'buffer is not a valid fragment qualifier'.

Comment: Edit your question to show the shader code and the Xcode error, verbatim.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion. Busy right now so don't wait on my edit but thanks for looking at the question.